# Don't know how to fix my PropertyChangeListener on a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, listener, jformattedtextfield, propertychangelistener

### EDIT at end of post

### Test Code and Output

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class Test{
    private JFormattedTextField input, input2;
    private NumberFormatter formatter;
    private PropertyChangeListener listener;
    
    
    public Test(){
       formatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
       input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
       input2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
       listener = new PropertyChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                convert(evt);
            }
        };
       input.setColumns(4);
       input2.setColumns(4);
       input.addPropertyChangeListener("value", listener);
       input2.addPropertyChangeListener("value", listener);
       input.setValue(0.0);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(input);
       panel.add(input2);
       
       
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
    
    private void convert(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
        if (evt.getSource()== input){
            if (evt.getSource()!= null){
                double temp;
                temp = converter((Double)evt.getNewValue());
                input2.setValue(temp);
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
              new Test(); 
           } 
        });
        
    }
    
    private double converter(double value){
        value = value*2;
        
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at test.Test.convert(Test.java:46)
```

---

### My thoughts

Because I have a method that passes in a `double` (it's `convert()`) , and seemingly `evt.getNewValue()` returns the direct value, which at the time of input is technically a `long`, it's throwing that error.

But every attempt at `parsing` my `evt.getNewValue()` to a double hasn't worked.  Perhaps a little knowledge of what I'm trying to do with this program would help.

---

### What The Program is for

So I've got a `JPanel` (in a `tabbedPane`) that has two `JFormattedTextField` inputs.  It's a conversion application.  My conversion `class method` passes in a `double` and returns a `double`.  I'd like the fields to be linked together, or in other words, as soon as one field's input is changed the other changes with it (as in it's the output of the conversion).

I was considering scrapping the `PropertyChangListener` and going for a `DocumentListener` instead, but opted to try the former first as the latter has 3 `overrideable` `methods` I have to take care of, one of which might cause some unexpected results (highlighting and deleting the field would trigger two `events` for example).

---

### TL;DR:

Is there a better way of getting a dynamically updating, dual input field application?  Input one number into one field and the other field's number automatically updates.

Still a novice at Java.

---

### Edit1

I've found a temporary solution:  Have a `DecimalFormat` as the format in the `JFormattedTextField`.  But if it could work without having a decimal as well I'd love it.

### Edit2

Question answered, didn't realize `evt.getNewValue()` was returning a `Number` instance.

Comment: `as soon as one field's input is changed the other changes with it ` - A PropertyChangeListener is only fired when the change is committed on a formatted text field. Therefore, the DocumentListener would be the better choice so the changes occur as you type. Multiple events is not an issue

Comment: @camickr  Was just about to ask this question too.  Right now it actually updates instantaneously, but only on the first focus and if I'm adding numbers.  Otherwise I have to lose focus on the field for it to update the other field.  Gonna attempt a document listener though thanks.

Comment: @camickr Ok so I attempted to use a Document Listener.  It only updates with loss of focus, so it's even less of what I wanted.  Gonna fiddle around with it to see if I can't fix that.

Comment: A DocumentListener works on every character I type. You only need to handle the `insertUpdate()` and `removeUpdate()` events. The `changeEvent()` is for attribute changes which are not applicable for text fields.

Comment: @camickr It works, but only if I change focus from the text field.

I dont' know why, I've gotten oracles demo document listener working exactly like I want my program to, but my program won't do it.

Comment: @camickr  Ok so I actually figured out how to do it with a `PropertyChangeListener()`.  Just have to `requestfocus()` on the field once the `event` is triggered.  IE `input1.requestFocus()`.  Thanks though

Comment: A DocumentListener works fine for me using your example code (on Windows 7 using JDK7). You do not need to lose focus for the Document event to be fired. Post your `SSCCE` if you have a problem. A PropertyChangeListener and a requestFocus() makes no sense. A PropertyChange Event is NOT generated as your type into the text field.

Comment: @camickr working on uploading both 'version' jar files.  One will have the `PropertyChangeListener` with the `requestFocus()` and the other a document listener.  I should say the `requestFocus()` works because its resetting the focus on the field, and everytime I'd started the program a fresh focus would insantaniously change the other field, albiet once.

Comment: @camickr scratch that i'll just upload my project.  Because JoptionPanes seem to not like updating...wasn't able to replicate my results from my main project in my testing one.

Comment: @camickr [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6j9gfauhdewn4ds/Desktop.zip) you go!.  Only included the relavant .java file source, but the .jar file is compilied with that exact .java file.

Comment: I deal with a proper SSCCE. The point of a SSCCE is to isolate the problem in minimal code. Also, this is a different issue and a new question should be posted if you can't get a DocumentListener working on a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: @camickr it was 2 in the morning, I was tired and didn't feel like writing out a whole new test project. 
It's not that the document listener didn't work, it just didn't update unless focus was lost.  So I'd have to click the other textfield for an update.

Comment: I don't care what time it is in the morning. It is not appropriate for you to continue to post questions and not listen to the advice given because you are too tired. Think of the volunteers on the forum. You are the one asking for help so the least you can do is make an effort!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you know for sure is that the object returned by `evt.getNewValue()` is a `Number` object. What if you use that information to your advantage and try something along these lines:

```
temp = ((Number)evt.getNewValue()).doubleValue();
```

Comment: And sweetness you are my savior.

Thank you will mark as answered as soon as I'm allowed