# PropertyChangeListener requestFocus issue

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, propertychangelistener

### Completely New Direction

Following is the SSCCE of my issue.  I'm trying to get the fields to update as input is being entered, in this case focus MUST be lost for an update to occur.

```
package test;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class Test {

    private JFormattedTextField input, input2;
    private NumberFormatter formatter;
    private DocumentListener listener;

    public Test() {
        formatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        input2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

        listener = new DocumentListener() {

            private Document source = null;

            protected void update(Document doc) {
                if (source == null) {
                    System.out.println("Update");
                    source = doc;
                    if (source.equals(input.getDocument())) {
                        double temp;
                        temp = converter(((Number)input.getValue()).doubleValue());
                        input2.setValue(temp);
//                        input2.setText(Double.toString(temp));
                    } else if (source.equals(input2.getDocument())) {                       
                        double temp;
                        temp = converterBack(((Number)input2.getValue()).doubleValue());
                        input.setValue(temp);
//                        input.setText(Double.toString(temp));
                    }
                    source = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }
        };

        input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        input2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        input.setColumns(4);
        input2.setColumns(4);
        input.setValue(0.0);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(input2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });

    }

    private double converter(double value) {
        value = value * 2;

        return value;
    }
    private double converterBack(double value){
        value = value/2;
        
        return value;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to utilize this code with a 'converter' `method`, so putting the commands into the `method Update()` isn't an option.

I have gotten this to work with `PropertyChangeListener` but apparently it's not a good route to take.

Comment: Haven't really looked at your coded, but this seems like a job for `DocumentListener` and not `PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: @peeskillet For some reason DocumentListener doesn't work for me in this case.  I mean to say it works, but only if I hit the enter key.

Comment: @Eric Then you're not using a `DocumentListener`...

Comment: @eric, what part of use a DocumentLIstener did you not understand from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776172/dont-know-how-to-fix-my-propertychangelistener-on-a-jformattedtextfield)? Why did you not post a SSCCE showing how you attempted to use the DocumentListener like you were asked to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PropertyChangeListener` isn't going to work for this problem, as the field's `Document` won't raise events...The `Document` is a property of the field, but it's contents is not.

A better solution would be to use a `DocumentListener`.  This will notify when the underlying document contents has changed.

You need to be careful with this, as a `Document` does not like been changed while it's already undergoing a change.

In this example, I use the source `Document` of the event and compare it to each fields `Document` to determine what should be updated...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class Test {

    private JFormattedTextField input, input2;
    private NumberFormatter formatter;
//    private PropertyChangeListener listener;
    private DocumentListener listener;

    public Test() {
        formatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        input2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

        listener = new DocumentListener() {

            private Document source = null;

            protected void update(Document doc) {
                if (source == null) {
                    System.out.println("Update");
                    source = doc;
                    if (source.equals(input.getDocument())) {
                        input2.setText(input.getText());
                    } else if (source.equals(input2.getDocument())) {
                        input.setText(input2.getText());
                    }
                    source = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                update(e.getDocument());
            }
        };
//        listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
//                convert(evt);
//            }
//        };

        input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        input2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);

        input.setColumns(4);
        input2.setColumns(4);
//        input.addPropertyChangeListener("value", listener);
//        input2.addPropertyChangeListener("value", listener);
        input.setValue(0.0);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(input2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }

    private void convert(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == input) {
            if (evt.getSource() != null) {
                double temp;
                temp = converter((Double) evt.getNewValue());
                input2.setValue(temp);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });

    }

    private double converter(double value) {
        value = value * 2;

        return value;
    }

}
```

**Updated**

The problem you're having with your conversion is the fact that the value has not yet been "committed", meaning it has not been validated and the `value` property has not yet been changed.

Calling `getValue` will return the last committed value.

What you need to do is commit the edit first...

```
if (source.equals(input.getDocument())) {
    try {
        input.commitEdit();
        double temp = ((Number) input.getValue()).doubleValue();
        temp = converter(temp);
        input2.setValue(temp);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: I suppose I was using it wrong then, because while I could get the fields to update with the Document listener they would only update if I deliberately clicked away.  Thanks for this answer

Comment: Ok scratch that, your program isn't doing what I want it to do still.  Is it a scope issue?  Because I'm not simply trying to copy the field over, I'm converting it from one number to another.

Comment: Okay...see the `update` method...change it to do what you want it to ;) - It's bi-directional and based on the field/document that is been updated...

Comment: Oh no I've changed it, and yes it does convert but it's not instantanious.  As in it will ONLY update if I lose focus, no exceptions. I don't know why it's doing this.  Your version of just copying the text works, but if I try to just double the number via my method convert, it now requires me to lose focus on the input field for an update to occur.

Comment: @eric, don't tell us what is happening. Show us what is happening by posting your own SSCCE. You were asked to do this yesterday and yet you still have not posted the SSCCE. As you can see the advice to use a DocuentListener has been given again and you are just wasting peoples time by saying "it doesn't work". Prove it doesn't work by posting the SSCCE and then maybe someone will be able to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: @camickr Sure thing, just gonna past the .java file then.  Literally his code above with a few tweaks.  [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udw8k899pm0o8nf/Test.java)

Comment: @MadProgrammer [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udw8k899pm0o8nf/Test.java) is me tweaking the update code, and it's not changing until focus is lost.  got yelled at for not including the SSCCE...

Comment: @eric, again you were asked in your last question to post the SSCCE in this question. The code should be posted in the forum for everybody to read.

Comment: @camickr do you want me to post a new question then?  or edit the code into my origional question.  Because I posted you a dropbox link.

Comment: @Eric Updated...It would have been more useful to update the current question based on the fact that you've found that the original question was lacking, but that is sometimes a hard call to make..

Comment: @MadProgrammer I apologize, I have updated the question, it's as simple as possible.

Comment: @Eric Check the update to the answer for an explanation of what's been going wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, I shall be more to the point in the future, I somewhat didn't know what I was asking for in the first place though.  Just wondering though why you didn't have to committ the edit with the original code

Comment: @Eric I was calling `get/setText` not `get/setValue`.  The later requires the edit to be committed successfully first before the property is changed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer As soon as I asked that I saw the answer haha.  Thanks for your help